# Change column name in Downloads section from email notifications in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, email-notifications

I'm creating a website with downloadable products with WooCommerce. When users buy a product and receive an email, I want to customize the table of downloadable products in the email. More specific I only want to change the following:

Only thing I want to do is change 'Downloads' and 'download' to something else…
[image: screenshot]

With some research, I thought I had the answer. I changed some things in [`order/order-details.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/order/order-details.php) and [`order/order-downloads.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/order/order-downloads.php). But I think I didn't do it correctly.

Can someone tell me what I have to change exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the title **"Downloads"**, the right template involved is [`emails/email-downloads.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/emails/email-downloads.php#L22) line 22

```
?><h2 class="woocommerce-order-downloads__title"><?php esc_html_e( 'Downloads', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>
```

To change the column label name **"Download"**, you will use the following code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_downloads_columns', 'custom_email_downloads_columns', 10, 1);
function custom_email_downloads_columns( $columns ){
    $columns['download-file'] = __("New name", "woocommerce");

    return $columns;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.